# Bootstrap responsive and select boxes

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I have a very simple form. The code below is a stripped down version with just one line os selects and all php code removed, but still shows my problem. When on a large screen, the label and the two select are nicely lined up. When on a small screen everything is placed vertically. There is ample room to keep thing next to each other, so there is no need to change the layout when moving to a small screen. Waht class should I override to keep things lined up? (I know I really don't need Bootstrap for this, but I consider this a learning experience).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Alarmtijden &middot; Twitter Bootstrap</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">


    <style type="text/css">
      body {
        padding-top: 40px;
        padding-bottom: 40px;
        background-color: #f5f5f5;
      }

      .form-signin {
        max-width: 250px;
        padding: 19px 29px 29px;
        margin: 0 auto 20px;
        background-color: #fff;
        border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
        -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
           -moz-border-radius: 5px;
                border-radius: 5px;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
           -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
                box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
      }

      .control-label2 {
        float: left;
        width: 100px;
        padding-top: 5px;
      }

      .controls2 {
        *display: inline-block;
        *padding-left: 0px;
        margin-left: 0px;
        margin-top: 10px;
        *margin-left: 0;
      }
      .controls3 {
        *display: inline-block;
        *padding-left: 0px;
        margin-left: 180px;
        *margin-left: 0;
      }

    </style>

    <!-- HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML5 elements -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="../assets/js/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

</head>

  <body>

<div class="container">
  <div class="form-signin">
    <div class="row-fluid">
      <form class="form-horizontal" action="alarms.php" method="post" id="alarms">
        <fieldset>
          <div id="legend">
            <legend class=""> <h2>Alarmtijden</h2></legend>
          </div>


          <!-- Alarm1-->
          <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label2" for="password"><h4>Alarm 1 </h4></label>
            <div class="controls2">
              <select class="span3" name="t_uur1" id="t_uur1">
                <option value="0">00</option>
                <option value="01">01</option>
                <option value="02">02</option>
                <option value="03">03</option>
                <option value="04">04</option>
                <option value="05">05</option>
                <option value="06">06</option>
                <option value="07">07</option>
                <option value="08">08</option>
                <option value="09">09</option>
                <option value="10">10</option>
                <option value="11">11</option>
                <option value="12">12</option>
                <option value="13">13</option>
                <option value="14">14</option>
                <option value="15">15</option>
                <option value="16">16</option>
                <option value="17">17</option>
                <option value="18">18</option>
                <option value="19">19</option>
                <option value="20">20</option>
                <option value="21">21</option>
                <option value="22">22</option>
                <option value="23">23</option>
              </select>&nbsp;:&nbsp;
              <select class="span3" name="t_minuut1">
                <option value="00">00</option>
                <option value="10">10</option>
                <option value="20">20</option>
                <option value="30">30</option>
                <option value="40">40</option>
                <option value="50">50</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>

        <!-- Submit -->
          <div class="control-group">
            <div class="controls3">
              <button class="btn btn-primary" name="submit" id="submit" type="submit">Set</button>
            </div>
          </div>

        </fieldset>
        </form>
      </div> 
  </div>   
</div> <!-- /container -->



  </body>
</html>
```

I also tried "form-inline" in stead of "form-horizontal" but that makes no difference.

Answer (score 0):

If it wouldn't be vertical alignment on small screens then you would get horizontal scroll bar which is bad practice.

Comment: Normally that would be true, but this layout is only 250 px wide, so even on a phone screen there is enough room for all the elements without the need for scrollbars.

Answer (score 0):

My advice is that you should use media queries and there you should float:left all your DIVs. 
If that doesn't work then your select boxes are to wide for that resolution.

Comment: Sure, like I said, you don't really need Bootstrap for this. Normally I would use media queries, but the rest of this site is set up in Bootstrap so I figured this should be possible too. Bootstrap responsive takes care of the media queries, only not in the way I'd like. So my question remains, what to override in Bootstrap to keep the selects aligned.

Comment: If you add your own specific class/id to DIV then you can use media query and float:left !important; for those DIVs. This will overwrite default CSS from bootstram.